# Buildling an array of vaules from page elements in JQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of text boxes in which the user inputs an email address into each one. I want to loop around these and build an array of them. How do I do it?

```
var emailAddresses = new Array();
 $(".email_address").each(
        function() {
                    //add this $(this).val() emailAddresses                                                                   
        }
 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var emailsArr = $('.email_address').map(function(i,n) {
    return n.value; //or $(n).val() or $(n).attr('value')
}).get();
```

See [$.map](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.map) for an awesomely concise way to do this sort of thing. `get` converts the returned collection into an array. Hope that helped.

Comment: Thanks, I through there would be a nice shorthand way of doing it.